# Comparing files from different folders

Tags: c#, file-io

I am trying to search files in path1. If that file exists in path2, it will be listed on a listView.

Here is my code. It doesn't seem to work...

```
string path = @"C:\temp\code\path1";
string path2 = @"C:\temp\code\path2";
string fileType = "*.h";

DirectoryInfo d1 = new DirectoryInfo(path);
DirectoryInfo d2 = new DirectoryInfo(path2);

foreach (FileInfo f1 in d1.GetFiles(fileType, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    foreach (FileInfo f2 in d2.GetFiles(fileType, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        if (f1 == f2)
        {
            lstProjectFiles.Items.Add(f1.Name).SubItems.Add(path);
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("False");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you comparing those files! file name,content...

Comment: Files with same name won't be the same always..They may contain different data!

Comment: Yes I know. In this case, if they have different data, the file in path1 will replace the file in path2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compare `f1 == f2`, you're comparing references of `FileInfo` objects which will be different. You need to compare the names of the files and their subfolders (I'm removing the beginning of the folder name to leave the common part only):

```
if (f1.FullName.Replace(path, "") == f2.FullName.Replace(path2, ""))
```

This comparison is based on file name and it's location in the folder structure.

Comment: Files with same name won't always be same

Comment: @Anirudh True, they may be in different subfolders, I'll correct that.

Comment: am talking about the content of files

Comment: Your previous code was correct..`Name` property would return just the name of file with extension..No need of `FullName.Replace`

Comment: @Anirudh But files with the same name may be in different folders.

Answer (score 0):

you should just use the Name property of the [FileInfo class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee433606.aspx). There is other useful info in the FileInfo class, but this will not tell you for certain that the files contain the same data (not sure if that is what you are even trying to do).

```
       string path = @"C:\temp\code\path1";
        string path2 = @"C:\temp\code\path2";
        string fileType = "*.h";


        DirectoryInfo d1 = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        DirectoryInfo d2 = new DirectoryInfo(path2);

        foreach (FileInfo f1 in d1.GetFiles(fileType, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            foreach (FileInfo f2 in d2.GetFiles(fileType, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                if (f1.Name == f2.Name)
                {
                    // you could also test the size before comparing actual data
                    if (f1.Length == f2.Length)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("these files might be the same: {0}, {1}", f1.Name, f2.Name));
                    }
                    //lstProjectFiles.Items.Add(f1.Name).SubItems.Add(path);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("False");
                }
            }
        }
```